# Same height for divs with auto height with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble equalizing the height of two floating divs. What I am trying to accomplish is displaying the 
same height in two divs that are side by side as the length of the content will be changing. Right now my browser seems to just ignore the Jquery code.

Here is what I have:

```
<style>
#column_first {
    width: 300px
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#column_second {
    width:300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:#fff;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var maxHeight = 0;

$("#column_first").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$("#column_second").height(maxHeight);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="column_first"><p>Some Text</p></div>
<div id="column_second"><p>Some Text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to equalize the height of your divs, use this:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$("div").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});
$("div").height(maxHeight);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kW2Jq/)**

You're targeting specific divs via their IDs, so the changes won't apply to all the divs. Personally I'd give them a common class and target that instead.

Note, also be sure to wrap your jQuery in a document ready call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* get equal height columns with pure CSS:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/dxtwufys

```
body { /* styles for the container element */
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 15px;
}

#column_first, #column_second {
    display: table-cell;
}

#column_first {
    width: 300px;
    /*margin: 15px; ignored*/
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#column_second {
    width:300px;
    /*margin: 15px; ignored*/
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```